# wildcard subdomain issue with links to other pages

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I’m having troubles linking to pages when using a wildcard subdomain and would love a little help figuring out a solution.

I want the users to have their own subdomain to view their own website content so if a user types in "user1.domain.com" the server would have a rewrite rule that directs the request to the index.php page in the root directory.  This index.php page will be used for all subdomains and will serve the content out of a db based on the subdomain passed in the querystring.

This part is working great and it serves up the content from index.php as it should.  When index.php page loads it includes a menu (HOME  |  RENTALS  |  CONTACT US). The problem comes when I click on the menu link to go to another page.  The URL address changes, but the page content does not.

Here's an example:  If I click on "RENTALS" I want the user to go to the rentals.php page and display the rentals available for the "user1" subdomain...but here's what is happening:

Link scenario 1:

```
<a href="http://user1.domain.com/rentals.php">RENTALS</a>   --> URL address bar changes to "user1.domain.com/rentals.php" but the page doesn't change, it still stays on the index.php content
```

Link scenario 2:

```
 < a href="rentals.php" >RENTALS< /a >   --> URL address bar changes to "user1.domain.com/rentals.php" but the page doesn't change, it still stays on the index.php content
```

Link scenario 3 (if I hardcode the domain and ommit the wildcard subdomain the link works):

```
<a href="http://www.domain/public_site/rentals.php">RENTALS</a>   --> URL address bar changes to "http://www.domain.com/public_site/rentals.php" AND IT WORKS, the rentals.php page loads and serves up the content.
```

The problem with scenario 3 is I want the url to read: "user1.domain.com/rentals.php"

I'm wondering if this can be setup in a rewrite condition, but I'm not able to figure it out.

If anyone can help I would be grateful!

Here is my directory structure:

```
ROOT
  |
  PUBLIC_SITE
     |
     index.php
     rentals.php
     contactus.php
```

Here is the apache rewrite rule (the 1st rule works.  the 2nd rule I added hoping to solve my problem, but it didn't solve the problem):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On

   ####Rewrite subdomain request to public_site/index.php
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /public_site/index.php?subdomain=%2 [L]

   #### Rewrite rule for rentals.php page
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com/rentals.php [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /public_site/rentals.php?s=%2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out on my own after getting into the rewrite...

simply put this code before the "main domain" rules:

```
#### Rewrite rule for rentals.php page
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rentals.php?$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /public_site/rentals.php [L]
```